# Adding up value and store in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build an app for vending machine simulator and I store the value in Firebase.

This is my Firebase data for coin denomination and drink quantity:

[image: This is my Firebase data for coin denomination and drink quantity]

This is my first activity:
[image: This is my first activity]

This is my second activity
[image: This is my second activity]

I want to store coin entered by the customer in each denomination (e.g.: if customer enter 20 cent, the quantity for 20 cent will be added by 1 in Firebase and so on) but I don't know how to do this. Same problem happen for drink quantity (e.g.: If the amount = price or amount > price, the system should dispense the drink and deduct the quantity of drink by 1 in Firebase).

I understand the logic, but I don't know how to implement it in android development since I'm still learning and new to this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

This is my DrinkActivity.java

```
public class DrinkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button terminateBtn;
    ImageButton tenCent, twentyCent, fiftyCent, oneRinggit, slugCoin1, slugCoin2;
    TextView amount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink);

        // Receive data
        String name  = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
        String price = getIntent().getExtras().getString("price");
        String image_url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("img");

        // init view
        TextView tv_name = findViewById(R.id.aa_name);
        TextView tv_price = findViewById(R.id.aa_price);
        ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.aa_thumbnail);

        // setting values to each view
        tv_name.setText(name);
        tv_price.setText(String.valueOf(price));

        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_shape).error(R.drawable.loading_shape);

        // set image using Glide
        Glide.with(this).load(image_url).apply(requestOptions).into(img);

        //Amount
        amount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amountView);

        //Coin Button
        tenCent = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cent10);
        twentyCent = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cent20);
        fiftyCent = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cent50);
        oneRinggit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rm1);
        slugCoin1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.unknown1);
        slugCoin2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.unknown2);

        terminateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.terminateBtn);

        //Terminate button
        terminateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //When terminate the transaction, it should return the amount that already has
                //been inserted by the customer.
                Intent i = new Intent(DrinkActivity.this,Home.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        //10 cent button
        tenCent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        amount.setText("RM 0.10");
                        playSound();
                    }
                }, 1000);
                amount.setText("Checking...");
            }
        });

        //20 cent button
        twentyCent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        amount.setText("RM 0.20");
                        playSound();
                    }
                }, 1000);
                amount.setText("Checking...");
            }
        });

        //50 cent button
        fiftyCent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        amount.setText("RM 0.50");
                        playSound();
                    }
                }, 1000);
                amount.setText("Checking...");
            }
        });

        //RM 1 button
        oneRinggit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        amount.setText("RM 1.00");
                        playSound();
                    }
                }, 1000);
                amount.setText("Checking...");
            }
        });

        //Slug coin 1 button
        slugCoin1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(DrinkActivity.this, "Invalid Coin!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        amount.setText("RM 0.00");
                        slugCoinSound();
                    }
                }, 1000);
                amount.setText("Checking...");
            }
        });

        //Slug coin 2 button
        slugCoin2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(DrinkActivity.this, "Invalid Coin!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        amount.setText("RM 0.00");
                        slugCoinSound();
                    }
                }, 1000);
                amount.setText("Checking...");
            }
        });

    }

    public void playSound() {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.insert_coins);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void slugCoinSound() {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.change);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `runTransaction` method of firebase. Here is an example code you can use for the your 20 Cent coins. The code for the other coins is similar:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
DatabaseReference quantityRef = ref.child("yoururl/Coins/1/quantity");
quantityRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        Integer currentValue = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
        if (currentValue == null) {
            mutableData.setValue(0);
        } else {
            mutableData.setValue(currentValue + 1);
        }

        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       System.out.println("Value incremented");
    }
});
}
```

You could also implement it in the `addValueEventListener` but it is not safe against concurrency:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    DatabaseReference ref = youdatabaseRef.child("Coins/1");
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int quantity = (int) dataSnapshot.child("quantity").getValue();
            ref.child("quantity").setValue(quantity++);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
    });   
}
```

In the code ref is the reference to your firebase database. You code it like this:

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("server/saving-data/fireblog");
```

Comment: @Chxk is your url correct? What is not working? What kind of error do you get?